# Using variables in fat-free framework template

Tags: php, templates, fat-free-framework

I'm reading the fat-free framework user guide and want to try display a template which uses F3s own template language. The template is displayed, but the variable is not substituted and I don't know why.

**index.php**

```
$f3 = require('../f3/base.php'); // I moved the lib dir one level up
$f3->set('UI', 'ui/');

$f3->route('GET /*',
    function($f3) {
        $f3->set('test', 'foo');
        echo View::instance()->render('layout.html', 'text/html');
    }
);

$f3->run();
```

**layout.html** simply contains

```
{{ @test }}
```

and this is exactly what is displayed too, instead of "foo".
Other directives of the F3 template language don't seem to work either.

Am I missing a step to activate it first or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the template class instead of the view class

```
$f3 = require('../f3/base.php'); // I moved the lib dir one level up
$f3->set('UI', 'ui/');

$f3->route('GET /*',
    function($f3) {
        $f3->set('test', 'foo');
        echo Template::instance()->render('layout.html');
    }
);

$f3->run();
```

Comment: I just found your answer to a similar question in the F3 Google Group. Should've looked over there earlier. Thank you anyway!